# Escape double quotes in asp.net Onclick string

Tags: asp.net, data-binding, onclick, eval

I am trying to insert dynamic data into a onclick property for a control the code looks like this

```
onclick="openRadWindow('<%#Eval("ID";) %>','<%#Eval("ParentObjectID") %>');"
```

I cant get it to fire and the trouble seems to be the double quotes, what is the correct method on escaping the quotes so that this fires.

Answer (score 2):

You can do use a format string, like this:

```
onclick='<%# string.Format("openRadWindow(\"{0}, {1}\");", Eval("ID"), Eval("ParentObjectID")) %>'
```

Comment: I get the error Comma, ')', or a valid expression continuation expected.

Changing the onclick='<%# to <%= and it loads but it does not get the databind values 

Thanks

Comment: @Adonis - It's been a while since I did anything like this inline, if you replace `\"` with `\\"`, same result?

Comment: @Adonis - Have you checked the rendered HTML to make sure the databind expressions are working correctly?

Comment: Thanks to all, I got it working with the solution I added to the original post

Comment: @Adonis - That would be my preferred method as well, keeps it cleaner overall, you should add this as an answer though, not in the question....you can answer your own question :) None of the other answers will suffice here for a code-behind because no one knows your object structure :)

Comment: @Nick Thanks your response did send me in the right direction

Answer (score 1):

Is the event just not firing or are you getting any javascript errors as well.  Also, I would look at the HTML after the page has been rendered and make sure that the server tags are being processed correctly.  There are certain uses that cause them not to actually be processed and will remain <%# Eval("ID") %>.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to all I was able to get it working correctly using a different method. in the code behind I created a function and in the function I put the following code

```
Return String.Format("openRadWindow({0},{1});", photo.ID, photo.ParentObjectID)
```

and in the aspx I added `onclick="<%#MyFunction(DirectCast(Container.DataItem,Photo))%>`

Answer (score 0):

First thing I see is that semi-colon after "ID" - I think that might be causing your problems.

Comment: Thanks , I did not mean to have that there, but I don't have it in the code